# Docker и расположение файлов

Tags: docker, docker-machine

Поставил Docker на windows7 и столкнулся с проблемой: docker-machine всегда идет в определенную папку в "моих документах" и работает только оттуда.
Диск отведен под систему, и хранить на нем контейнеры не хотелось бы.
Соответственно возникает вопросы:
1. Как поменять путь для docker-machine и возможно ли это?
2. Можно ли создать docker-machine там, куда он хочет, а образы и контейнеры хранить на другом диске? Если да, то как?

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл инструкцию для изменения расположения файлов docker [вот здесь](https://blog.adriel.co.nz/2018/01/25/change-docker-data-directory-in-debian-jessie/). К сожалению, в ней описывается порядок действий для debian.

Думаю, стоит попробовать выполнить подобные действия, но с учётом путей для windows и перезапуском соответствующих служб.

Answer (score 0):

если вы используете Docker for Windows, то в настройках программы (`ПКМ по значку в трее -> Settings -> Disk image location`) Точнее не скажу так как сейчас нет доступа к машине с докером. Отпишу вечером подробней

**update**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]